# Why are separate method invocations considered the same Task?

Tags: c#, async-await

While debugging an issue, I've found that short running tasks are considered equal. I'd like to know why this is, and if there is any way of preventing this behavior.

Below, I've given a unit test (using mstest) that reproduces this behavior. If you uncomment the Task.Delay and introduce a delay, the test passes.

```
    private async Task successTaskFn()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(250);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync("Line1");
            await sw.WriteLineAsync("Line2");
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TaskIdsCheck()
    {
        var t1 = successTaskFn();
        var t2 = successTaskFn();
        var t3 = successTaskFn();

        Assert.AreNotSame(t1, t2);
        Assert.AreNotSame(t1, t3);
        Assert.AreNotSame(t2, t3);
    }
```

The test fails on AreNotSame, because the Task objects are considered the same.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, have updated to reflect this

Comment: Why is it a concern to you that they are the same or not? They both have the status of `RanToCompletion` (i.e. it is an optimisation). It you changed the function to `private Task successTaskFn()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }` you'd see the same behaviour. The `Delay` slows it down enough for the optimisation not to kick in.

Comment: See also https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233455-better-cached-completed-task

Comment: `MemoryStream` does not support async methods, thus `successTaskFn` is completely synchronous method and likely return `Task.CompletedTask` as optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important points at work here:

- Async methods run synchronously until the first await expression that is awaiting something that hasn't already completed.
- There are optimizations to reuse tasks where possible. This is only possible for *completed* tasks, and then only when the result is okay to cache. In your case you're not dealing with any tasks returning values - it's easy for "a completed task with no result" to be cached, as you only need one of them.

So if you have a method that does *nothing* asynchronous (no awaits at all) and just returns `Task`, that will *always* return the same `Task`. (It's no guaranteed, but that's the current behaviour.)

If you have a method that *does* have awaits, it will depend on what's being awaited. If the operation you await hasn't completed, the async machinery needs to do a complicated dance to box the state machine (the first time), schedule a continuation, and then return to the caller.

In your case, you're only awaiting the result of operations on `MemoryStream`. There's no point in `MemoryStream` being asynchronous for this sort of operation, so its async methods just return a completed task - which makes it work as if it were entirely synchronous.

If you use:

```
await Task.Yield();
```

that should prevent that behaviour, but I'd only do that in extreme cases. You simply shouldn't be *relying* on the identity of the returned task.